# openpty returning zero as master file descriptor

Tags: linux, c, serial-port, pty

I am opening a pseudoterminal with [openpty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openpty.3.html) function. This will be used to redirect some data coming from a serial port into an external application (in this case, a GPS receiver).

The fact is that sometimes I am getting a **zero for the amaster file descriptor** (in the code below, mpty paramter). In those cases the redirection does not work and the external app is not receiving any data, which I assume it is normal as zero is the [Standard Input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) descriptor.

What I am doing wrong? Is it possible to block the stdin to be the master with the openpty function?

Thanks in advance.

```
bool openPts(char* ptsName, int* mpty, int* spty) {

    if (openpty(mpty, spty, ptsName, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        printf("openPts: ERROR openpty [%d] %s",
            errno, strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }

//  if (*mpty == 0 || *spty == 0) {
//      printf("openPts: ERROR openpty mpty[%d] spty[%d] [%d] %s",
//          *mpty, *spty, errno, strerror(errno));
//
//      if (*mpty > 0) {
//          close(*mpty);
//      }
//      if (*spty > 0) {
//          close(*spty);
//      }
//      return false;
//  }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Set non-blocking
    if (setNonblock(*mpty) == -1) {
        printf("openPts: mpty[%d] NONBLOCK ERROR [%d] [%s]",
            *mpty, errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    if (setNonblock(*spty) == -1) {
        printf("openPts: spty[%d] NONBLOCK ERROR [%d] [%s]",
            *spty, errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    printf("openPts[%s]: fd MASTER[%d] fd SLAVE[%d]",
        ptsName, *mpty, *spty);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: zero is a legal file descriptor; you could get that result you had closed stdin (also legal).

Answer (score 1):

zero is a legal file descriptor.  The [`openpty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openpty.3.html) call will (like [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)) return a positive integer (zero or more).  They return `-1` on error.

A successful call returns a new (previously unused) file descriptor.  You could get this result you had closed **`stdin`** (also legal, done occasionally in daemon/service code).